# AttributeError: module '_version' has no attribute 'version' in mysql connector on docker

Tags: docker

I'm getting below error while trying to run the linux image container on windows 10 in docker desktop.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app1.py", line 17, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    __version__ = _version.version
AttributeError: module '_version' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question and include more information about what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Also include relevant code. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 using python3.5 with the package mysql_connector_repackaged installed via pip.

I solved by removing it and installing the package mysql-connector-python

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```